# On system boot, Grub is not letting me to choose between Operating systems but it does on system restart

Tags: windows-7, grub, ubuntu-16.04

he issue is when the system is booted for the first time, my Grub shows Ubuntu 16.04 as well as Windows 7 but it is not letting me to choose between operating system and boots Ubuntu.

On System Restart, Grub lets me to choose between operating systems and then I can boot either Ubuntu 16.04 or windows 7.

To be more accurate I have already updated my Grub.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible your GRUB config has a low `GRUB_TIMEOUT` setting and the monitor is just not able to switch modes (from BIOS resolution to GRUB resolution) before the time expires?

You could also try specifying a different resolution in the grub config (`GRUB_GFXMODE`) to see if perhaps the monitor can handle that switch better (assuming the video switch is the issue).